# how to rectify this error (start tag "div" seen in "table")

Tags: html

I am creating my website. The problem is when i see demo in my browser it seems ok but view page source marked it as red with an error that start tag a seen in table. please help....

```
<table width="165" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr>
     <div style="_height:px; width:px;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; text-align:justify;">
       <a href="http://www.amazon.com/" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none; color: #87A800;">This is a sample text</a>
    </div>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: See through that you have closed all tags properly and in order

Comment: Please who an example of what you see in the browser source view (screenshot)

Comment: Well, the div should not be there, wrap it in a `td`, because `tr` can only be a parent to a `td` or `th` element.

Answer (score 1):

You need a TD to make a cell inside the row (TR)

```
<table width="165" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr>
    <td>
     <div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; text-align:justify;">
       <a href="http://www.amazon.com/" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none; color: #87A800;">This is a sample text</a>
    </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Note that height and width needs real values. `px` it's not a value. `10px` is correct

Answer (score 1):

The only child elements a table row can have a table data cells and table header cells.

Since you don't appear to be using the table to structure tabular data, you should fix this error by removing the table entirely.

```
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; text-align:justify;">
   <a href="http://www.amazon.com/" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none; color: #87A800;">This is a sample text</a>
</div>
```